# Is a UK PAL video tape compatible with a continental Europe PAL VHS/S-VHS player in terms of video and sound

Tags: video-capture, video-standards, vhs, pal

I've read that the difference between UK PAL and Continental PAL is the carrier frequency used for the audio. But is that referring to:

- the (now former) analogue TV broadcasts
- the encoding on the tape
- or both?

I am aware of the VHS PAL I standard for the UK and the VHS PAL B/G etc standard in continental Europe.

According to these links, if the SCART output is used, then the audio is available. The links say that the difference in audio encoding is only related to the RF (Radio Frequency) signal i.e. broadcasts:

- [VHS tape recordings in the U.K. where else do they work?](https://forums.digitalspy.com/discussion/124554/vhs-tape-recordings-in-the-u-k-where-else-do-they-work)
- [can I convert a PAL-B/G signal to a PAL-I signal?](https://www.avforums.com/threads/can-i-convert-a-pal-b-g-signal-to-a-pal-i-signal.84444/)

My use case is for using a continental video player from Germany to play UK VHS PAL tapes and convert the video and audio digitally.

Setup:

- Model: JVC HR-S9600EU (not EK - UK) - one of the apparently higher quality machines, according to:

  - [VCR Buying Guide 1](http://www.digitalfaq.com/forum/video-restore/1567-vcr-buying-guide.html)
  - [VCR Buying Guide 2 - details of model codes such as EK and EU](http://www.digitalfaq.com/forum/video-restore/1567-vcr-buying-guide-2.html)
- Canopus ADVC100 attached to computer via Firewire

PAL standard references:

- http://martin.hinner.info/vga/pal.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAL#PAL-B/G/D/K/I

Answer (score 2):

The UK PAL VHS tapes will play back in a German PAL deck. The actual method of audio recording is not related to the PAL specification. VHS records up to two linear audio tracks. HiFi capable decks record additional two HiFi tracks that are  multiplexed with the video signal. I don't remember the details.

A non-HiFi deck will ignore the HiFi tracks and use the linear tracks which should have the same content recorded.

Comment: +1 thank you. Do you know how would I find out which audio is being played back - linear or HiFi ?

Comment: Older decks may have a physical switch. Newer models will default to HiFi if present. Another way to tell is by adjusting tracking. A small change in tracking may result in sudden loss of HiFi audio.